# My two month old cat bit me, could I get rabies?

Tags: cats, safety, vaccination

My kitten is UNVACCINATED but I live in Europe currently and where I live most rabies come from bats or dogs.

I was playing around with her with my hand as a mouse and other objects. She was also being played with someone else. She bit me but it was of a dot and bled a little. I also washed my hands like 40 times while playing with her. She is a indoor kitten only goes outside to do her business she mostly all the time moderated. I might have found out why she had bit me but be honest she was biting everything.

And someone else had her for two months and probably got bit so I had highly doubt I'd get rabies but I kept searching and other forums where they advise GO TO THE DOCTOR.

This is the thing I found not mine "Like babies and puppies, kittens tend to put objects in their mouths as a means of exploring and playing. They may chew because they are teething or just because it's fun. Some kittens chew out of boredom.Jan 20, 2015" it's kinda like how babies chew on the toys to get there teeth stronger also the kitten like most are very active so it was high chance high she bit me and scratched me a little.

I tried to make this more clear and re read everything and please if your gonna say "You have to go to the doctor" put something positive too because I always see on these forums doctors trying to tell you to take this medication and that while I barley see anyone who really had a Cat or a pet.
Thank you

Comment: this question is about human medicin and is therfore off topic here.you might start planning to get your cat vaccsinated and spayed/nutered in a month or so,unless your cat has started hunting the risk for rabies is limited but not zero.i am sorry but i have to flag your question as off topic but please continue to ask questions.

Comment: It's not off topic I never said anything about. Medicine I said what people might say

Comment: what is your question about,what problem do your cat have it is unclear to me what you are asking.

Comment: Related: [Rabies from a cat? Under what circumstances?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/q/2857/224)

Answer (score 6):

The odds your kitten has rabies are slim to none. Animals don't live very long once signs of rabies appear, some examples are:

- wanting to eat everything and anything
- fever
- seizures
- paralysis
- drooped jaw
- random bouts of aggression (not playful aggression)
- excessively salivating

Protocol for a bite from a suspected animal with rabies is quarantine for 14 days to monitor for more signs or death. 
If you have concerns, human hospitals will vaccinate you for rabies and do a treatment (I heard it's unpleasant).

If she's been in a home her entire life I wouldn't worry about rabies.